# creating cookies using raw javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Cookies should be created for the following fields: fname, lname, street, city, state, zip, email, and phone1-3. Persistent cookies should be created which are valid for 1 year. When the user returns to the page, cookies should be read and the individual form field values restored to the saved cookie values.

```
<html>
<body>
<input name="fname" id="fname">
<input name="lname" id="lname">
<input id="street" name="street" type="text">
<input id="city" name="city" type="text">
<select id="state" name="state"><option value="" selected="selected">Choose</option>
<input id="zip" name="zip" type="text">
<input name="email" id="email">
( <input id="phone1" name="phone1" size="3"> )
  <input id="phone2" name="phone2" size="3"> - 
  <input id="phone3" name="phone3" size="4">

<script type="text/javascript>

var regForm = document.getElementById("registration");
var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
var street = document.getElementById("street").value;
var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
var state = document.getElementById("state").options;
var zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var phone1 = document.getElementById("phone1").value;
var phone2 = document.getElementById("phone2").value;
var phone3 = document.getElementById("phone3").value;

function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        var expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value + expires;
    alert("Cookie being created " + document.cookie);
}
createCookie("first", fname, 365);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to call the function and pass the aurguments accordingly.               eg... createCookie('key', fname, 'the no of days')

Comment: @jp310 If he's getting the alert box, I think the function is being called.

Comment: don't include a path

Comment: Since I have fname set to the value of the first name input, I pass that as the value? Can I just make up any name for the cookie name? And days should be 365 so that the cookie is good for a year.

Comment: @KSFT He's calling the function. He just doesn't pass any arguments to it.

Comment: I added the arguments but now I get "Cookie being created value%3D; first=; name="

Comment: It works now! I edited the post with the updated code.  So I passed the arguments createCookie("first", fname, 365).  Now when the page is loaded the alert pops saying "Cookie being created name=" .  Then when I type a name in the input and reload the page the alert is updated with the new cookie created.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a private variable in your function, such as cookieToCreate.

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
  var cookieToCreate = '';  // Private var
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  }
  else var expires = "";
  cookieToCreate = name + '=' + value + expires + '; path=/;';
  document.cookie = cookieToCreate;
  alert("Cookie being created " + cookieToCreate);
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit of having a private variable in the function?  The code seems to work without adding one, but if it adds versatility then maybe I should add one.